# Parsing XML into records

Tags: xml, haskell

I’d like to write a Haskell library to work with a web service API. I get an XML or JSON response from the server, say it looks like this:

```
<foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
    <baz>moo</baz>
</foo>
```

I want to turn it into a record:

```
data Foo = Foo {
    bar :: Integer,
    baz :: String
}
```

How can I abstract this so that I don’t have to manually parse the XML and pick the individual components by hand? I hoped for an API that would let me describe the mapping from the XML elements and attributes to the record parts and do the rest for me.

Comment: Do you have a DOCTYPE or XML Schema for the API?

Comment: I don’t think so. Would it help? I wouldn’t mind writing it, but I’m afraid it would be mork work than writing the parsing code by hand.

Comment: It's actually necessary to know what types of data you expect in order to turn it into any data type (so also for records). It doesn't matter how you use it: you could hardcode it into a hand-written parser (as you're planning to do), or generate a parser from an XML Schema (using `XsdToHaskell` from [HaXml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml), for instance).

Comment: In the current absence of more specifi advice, you could look at [this question about which XML library to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361307/which-haskell-xml-library-to-use) for now.

Comment: @Tinctorius: Didn’t know about `XsdToHaskell`, will take a look, thank you. I know I would have to specify the data types, I was hoping I could simply pass a “deserialization” filter function to be applied to the attribute or element in question.

Comment: Another approach is using Template Haskell to automatically generate the code to "pick the individual components".